# Dr. Temperance Brennan security clearance

Tags: plot-explanation, bones

In the episode "[The woman in the car](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0758574/)" a one-time character, agent Pickering from the state department, is interviewing the employees at that branch of the Jeffersonian, with mostly humorous responses.

When she interviews Brennan, she asks about her relations with a Cuban national. Brennan gets on the phone, calls someone from the state department, and the investigation is suspended immediately, implying that Brennan has very high security clearance that includes some sensitive information, sensitive enough to have all of agent Pickering's notes destroyed.

Was Brennan's very-high security clearance ever explored in a later episode?  I've seen most of them, but missed a few of the last couple seasons.   I'm just curious if her clearance was every explored in more detail in a later episode.   I googled "Temperance Brennan security clearance" and all the references are to this episode only, so I'm thinking it was a one-off, but if anyone can point out any other episodes where it came up I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think they gave it much thought. Much later (season 9 or 10 I think) Bones has no such "power", and in order to help Booth escape some serious investigation she has to use other means, namely extortion. Will try to look further, but I'm afraid the answer would be about the same. (No special clearance)

Comment: It's possible that the issue was specific to the Cuban national in question, and her connection to said individual.

Comment: @RDFozz That occured to me as well.   Bones specialty is identification.   In theory, she identified remains from Cuba that show . . . something highly secret.    It could have been an interesting episode or two, but it seems, they never pursued it.  Too bad, they pursued some wacky stuff.   The secrets from the McCarthy era (if I remember right) struck me as the worst reveal in the show's run.